# How do I optimize a cut-off through cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation

Imagine I want to tune a penalized logistic regression and I have imbalanced classes so I want to optimise a F-alpha-measure = 1/(alpha/P +(1-alpha)/R), with alpha=0.25 (arbitrary choice I make which is not to be discussed here).

For a given model, let's say a ridge logistic regression (with a lambda shrinkage parameter), I will have as many F-alpha-measures as confusion matrices, so I will optimize the F-alpha-measure wrt the cut-off.

To sum up, my modelisation is entirely defined by : one lambda and one cutoff*

**But this is not clear for me how I get the cutoff during the cross validation for tuning lambda wrt my F-alpha-measure**

Let's say I have 5 folds, usually I would do a loop :

`criteria<-rep(0,length(grid))
for lambda in grid
    criteria_flds<-rep(0,5)
    for i in 1:5 
       train_i <- data[-folds[i],]
       test_i <- data[folds[i],]
       modl<-ridge(train_i, lambda)
       prediction<-predict(modl,test_i,cutoff=0.5)
       matrice_confusion<-table(test_i,prediction)
       criteria_flds[i]<- calcul_criteria(matrice_confusion)
    end
    criteria[j]<-mean(criteria_flds) #j corresponding to one lambda
end
lambda_opt<-which.max(criteria)`

This is not actually code but just the idea of the classic algorithm.

But if I want to optimise the cutoff, is it right to do this ?

`criteria<-rep(0,length(grid))
for lambda in grid
    criteria_flds<-rep(0,5)
    for i in 1:5 
       train_i <- data[-folds[i],]
       test_i <- data[folds[i],]
       modl<-ridge(train_i, lambda)
       criteria_cutoff<-rep(0,10)
       for cutoff in seq(0,1,by=0.1)
            prediction<-predict(modl,test_i,cutoff=cutoff)
            matrice_confusion<-table(test_i,prediction)
            criteria_cutoff[cutoff*10]<-calcul_criteria(matrice_confusion)
       end
       criteria_flds[i]<- max(criteria_cutoff)
    end
    criteria[j]<-mean(criteria_flds)
end
lambda_opt<-which.max(criteria)`

My problem is : what cutoff do I keep ? Does it really make sense to keep one cutoff corresponding to one measure taken on one fold ? Alternatively, I don't really think that the mean of the cutoffs for the lambda maximising the criteria would make sense either.

My final guess would be to set cutoff* like any other hyperparameter :

`criteria_lambda_cutoff<-matrix(0,N,P)#matrix of criteria initiated with zero, size of the grid (P values for cutoff, N for lambda)
for cutoff in seq(0,1,by=0.1)
for lambda in grid
    criteria_flds<-rep(0,5)
    for i in 1:5 
       train_i <- data[-folds[i],]
       test_i <- data[folds[i],]
       modl<-ridge(train_i, lambda)
       criteria_cutoff<-rep(0,10)
       prediction<-predict(modl,test_i,cutoff=cutoff)
       matrice_confusion<-table(test_i,prediction)
       criteria_flds[i]<-calcul_criteria(matrice_confusion)
    end
    criteria_lambda_cutoff[j,k]<-mean(criteria_flds) #j,k corresponding to some values of lambda and cutoff from tunegrid
end
end
lambda_opt,cutoff_opt<-which.max(criteria_lambda_cutoff)`

**Please, I know there are plenty of alternatives for handling imbalanced classes, you might think that the approach is not the best, but my question is really cut-off specific.**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There is no statistical basis for using such an accuracy score.  The gold standard is the log likelihood and measures derived from it such as generalized $R^2$ and effective AIC (AIC from penalized fits using effective degrees of freedom in the AIC formula).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, actually I took the example of penalized regression because it is simple to make the example, but I have plenty of models to compare. AIC is not adapted to most of them... My question is really about the cut-off. Since the F-alpha-measure exists, there must be some protocole about the choice of the corresponding cutoff.